# SignalObjectAndWait eqivalent for Linux in a single context switch

Tags: c, linux, windows, ipc

If I understand correctly the function SignalObjectAndWait in Windows could notify another process and wait in a single context switch, effectively replacing the current running process on cpu with a process waiting for that signal. From my search I couldn't find an equivalent on Linux that would do the transfer in a single context switch. I would like to know if there is a replacement and/or if my understanding of the matter is correct.

I need it for 2 programs that use ipcs a lot and optimizing the notification mechanism would bring a substantial improvement. Those programs, both do some cpu processing, singal the other process to continue and wait to be signaled back. If those computation could be chained it would be ideal, without placing them in the same process.